# Runing the blueocean plugin within a JenkinsPipelineUnit testcase

Tags: jenkins, testing, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-pipeline-unit

I'd like to use JenkinsPipelineUnit to test our Jenkins pipeline. We use the "blueocean" plugin in production. So, to test our Jenkins pipeline file, I need to do this:

```
   import io.jenkins.blueocean.rest.impl.pipeline.FlowNodeWrapper
```

That seems like it should be super simple; however, I cannot figure out the magic combination of keystrokes in my `build.gradle` file and my "DeclarativePipelineTest" implementation that allows the above line to work. `gradle test` just reports that it cannot resolve the import!

The [JenkinsPipelineUnit page on github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) only mentions plugins once, and only to say that a few widely used plugins are included!

So my question is: can I even do this? Does JenkinsPipelineUnit support plugins? Where's the documentation?

Thanks!